# Why can't columnar databases like Snowflake and Redshift change the column order?

Tags: database, amazon-redshift, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have been working with Redshift and now testing Snowflake. Both are columnar databases. Everything I have read about this type of databases says that they store the information by column rather than by row, which helps with the massive parallel processing (MPP).

But I have also seen that they are not able to change the order of a column or add a column in between existing columns (don't know about other columnar databases). The only way to add a new column is to append it at the end. If you want to change the order, you need to recreate the table with the new order, drop the old one, and change the name of the new one (this is called a [deep copy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/performing-a-deep-copy.html)). But this sometimes can't be possible because of dependencies or even memory utilization.

I'm more surprised about the fact that this could be done in row databases and not in columnar ones. Of course, there must be a reason why it's not a feature yet, but I clearly don't have enough information about it. I thought it was going to be just a matter of changing the ordinal of the tables in the information_schema but clearly is not that simple.

Does anyone know the reason of this?

Comment: Snowflake isn't using a strictly columnar data store.  (See https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/tables-clustering-micropartitions.html)

Comment: Good point. Still it doesn't allow column position change. I'm intrigued

Comment: In which row-based database can you change the order of columns or add a column in between?

Comment: "I'm more surprised about the fact that this could be done in row databases" - I would also be very surprised if this could be done in any database, whether the storage was row or column based, as in my experience it cannot. You might have experienced something like the visual database designer in SQL Server, which makes it *appear* that you can re-order columns but does in fact select the data into a new table with a new schema in the background.

Comment: changing the order of the column is an meaningless operation. order of columns has zero impact on anything. And you can control the order of the column in your select, which you should be doing as a select * give slower access to the same columns as snowflake has to read all partitions metadata to know the output columns prior to streaming the results.

Comment: If well I agree with you on the fact that `select *` gives you slower access, every time you see new data you need to `select *` to understand how the table is structured and the information in the table. All the analysts I work with, and myself, would benefit from having the order of the columns in `select *` in a logical order rather than everything out of place.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, column ordering within the table is not considered to be a first class attribute. Columns can be retrieved in whatever order you require by listing the names in that order.

Emphasis on column order within a table suggests frequent use of `SELECT *`. I'd strongly recommend not using `SELECT *` in columnar databases without an explicit `LIMIT` clause to minimize the impact.

If column order must be changed you do that in Redshift by creating a new empty version of the table with the columns in the desired order and then using `ALTER TABLE APPEND` to move the data into the new table very quickly.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ALTER_TABLE_APPEND.html

Answer (score 0):

The order in which the columns are stored internally cannot be changed without dropping and recreating them.

Your SQL can retrieve the columns in any order you want.

General requirement to have columns listed in some particular order is for the viewing purpose.

You could define a view to be in the desired column order and use the view in the required operation.

```html
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE CO_TEST(B NUMBER,A NUMBER);
INSERT INTO CO_TEST VALUES (1,2),(3,4),(5,6);
SELECT * FROM CO_TEST;
SELECT A,B FROM CO_TEST;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW CO_VIEW AS SELECT A,B FROM CO_TEST;
SELECT * FROM CO_VIEW;
```

Creating a view to list the columns in the required order will not disturb the actual table underneath the view and the resources associated with recreation of the table is not wasted.

Answer (score 0):

In some databases (Oracle especially) ordering columns on table will make difference in performance by storing NULLable columns at the end of the list. Has to do with how storage is beiing utilized within the data block.